# R substitute NAs in a matrix

Tags: r

in R I have a data frame with some missing values so the `read.table()` function uses `NA`s instead of blank cells.

I wrote this:

```
a <- sample(1000:50000000, size=120, replace=TRUE)
values <- matrix(a, nrow=6, ncol=20)
mtx <- cbind.data.frame(values, c(rep(NA),6))
mtx <- apply(mtx, 2, function(x){
    if (x==NA) sample(100:500, replace=TRUE, size=nrow(mtx)) else (x)})
```

but I have this error:

```
Error in if (x == NA) sample(100:500, replace = TRUE, size = nrow(mtx)) else (x) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (x == NA) sample(100:500, replace = TRUE, size = nrow(mtx)) else (x) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any ideas?

Best
Riccardo

Comment: `?NA` tells you how to test for `NA`... and `if` doesn't work on vectors, as is stated in `?"if"`, "cond: A length-one logical vector that is not 'NA'.".

Answer (score 8):

You can't test for `NA` using comparison operators for the very reason that the value is `NA` or missing. `is.na()` is the appropriate function for identifying missingness in the form of `NA`.

Here is an example of replacing `NA` in a matrix `values`. The key here is work in a vectorised fashion and just identify which elements are `NA` then index using to to replace all the `NA` with the values you need.

```
> set.seed(2)
> values <- matrix(sample(1000:50000000, size=120, replace=TRUE),
+                  nrow=6, ncol=20)
> ## add some NA to simulate
> values[sample(120, 20)] <- NA
> 
> ## how many NA
> (tot <- sum(is.na(values)))
[1] 20
> 
> ## replace the NA
> values[is.na(values)] <- sample(100:500, tot, replace=TRUE)
> 
> ## now how many NA
> (sum(is.na(values)))
[1] 0
```

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich If I'd seen your comment before I started writing I may not have been so saintly :-)

Comment: You should always check for my comments, especially because I often use them to answer questions. ;-)