# How can I remove NaN values from a document term matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am using RTextTools to build a training set with a matrix and a model which I will later apply to different documents to classify them.

**EDIT:** The matrix is a Document Term Matrix

The problem I am having is that sometimes with certain documents when I create the `new_matrix` with the following line

```
new_matrix <- create_matrix(data$document,language="english", removeNumbers=FALSE, removePunctuation=TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE, toLower=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, minDocFreq=1,weighting=weightTfIdf,originalMatrix=matrix)
```

I get some `NaN` values which make my corpus fail

```
corpus <- create_corpus(new_matrix,data$value, testSize=1:100,virgin=FALSE)
```

With the error

```
Error in .csr.coo(x) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

I am not sure why there are some `NaN` values. My guess is that it has to do with some words being present on the new_matrix and not on the original matrix.

How can I change `NaN` values for a 0 in the resulting matrix?

Will doing that alter the result of the classification?

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Related: [R substitute NAs in a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11140650/271616).

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that works for a matrix but not for a document term matrix

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help.
Failing that, you can just look at the contents of the matrix (`str(new_matrix)`),
notice it is just a list of positions and values,
and remove the offending ones 
(`m <- new_matrix; i <- is.finite(m$v); m$i <- m$i[i]; m$j <- m$j[i]; m$v <- m$v[i]`).

Comment: Thanks Vincent! You gave me an idea. I noticed after using `str(new_matrix)` that the `NaN` values where all in `new_matrix$v` with that I run the code provided by DWAHL and now I can modify the `NaN` values for a `0`. I have yet to understand if that alters the results of the machine learning algorithms but its a good step. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way to find NaN values by using is.na():

```
data<-c(1,2,NaN,4,2)
data[is.na(data)]<-0
data
```

[1] 1 2 0 4 2

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it is not working for my matrix, the output after running it is the same. Here is my code [new_matrix[is.na(new_matrix)]<-0.It seems to work fine with vectors.

Comment: correction, it seems to work with matrices but not with document term matrices

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead developer of RTextTools, and would really appreciate if you could send me an example of this error. The originalMatrix parameter was introduced within the past two months, and there may be some ongoing issues with how it is processed. You can drop me an email on my website (http://www.timjurka.com/)